# НЕ могу добавить ссылку на проэкт,а так же не видит ее

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Когда пытаюсь добавить ссылку на проэкт выдеает ошибку.

```
 Невозможно найти экземпляр службы Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Inteertop.IvsReferenceManager
```

Погугли нашел пару решений которые не привели в нужному результату

```
gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll
```

Добавил,но ошибка все так же остается.

Не могу скомпилировать проэкт так как ругаетсz,что нет ссылки на проэкт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял быстрым поиском по тексту ошибки, там нужна немного более сложная операция:

[отсюда](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-find-an-instance-of-the-microsoftvisualstud-1/664792):

> Finally got gacutil to work. I cannot say why, but some gacutil related files were needed and I had to copy manually to the "PublicAssemblies" folder. Those files were: gacutlrc.dll and gacutil.exe.config
>
> After copying the files, I ran "gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll" and finally I saw the "dll was added to gac" message. I restarted VS2019 and now I can use the "Add Reference" feature without problems

Также, там автор шлет благодарности такому [вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196832/my-gacutil-vs2010-4-0-does-not-seem-to-be-working)

Comment: Спасибо,это сработало для меня и собрала проэкт)

Comment: Главное, что помогло!